# How to trigger a function everyday at the same time with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, timer, unusernotificationcenter

I'm building a quote app with SwiftUI. I would like to send a user notification and get a new quote every day at the time that the user picks.

I've tried it with Timer but there is a problem if the user terminates the app. Also tried it with notification but if the user declines the permission, I can't update the quotes and the whole app is useless. I would appreciate it if anybody has an idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Your app can´t perform tasks at an exact point in time if it is in background. Explain the user why it is mandatory to accept notifications. If they decide to not allow them, respect their choice.

Comment: Look into background tasks but it isn't exact and the user can turn that off too. The best you can do is let the user know that having notifications off or declining background processing affects the app performance.

Comment: Ok, I'll write a good explanation for the notification and figure something out if the user still declines. Thanks!